# Switching regulator rated for 3 A but doesn't power a device that needs 2 A

Tags: voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project that utilizes a 5 V fixed buck regulator (LM2576T-005G) to step down 12 VDC input from a wall supply in order power a Raspberry Pi 4B on a PCB. The circuit and passive elements are exactly what is listed and recommended in the datasheet.

Even though the regulator states that it can supply 3 A, the Raspberry Pi keeps stating that it is finding under-voltage conditions (power supply is ~4.6 V instead of 5 V).

I cut a trace and measured current supplied on the 5 V line and I'm only seeing roughly 0.3-0.5 A being pulled by the Pi, even though datasheets say the Pi needs 2 A. I have tried multiple Raspberry Pis and they all have the same issue. No other devices/parts pull from 5 V on the PCB.

I was under the impression that this part could supply the amperage that the Pi needs, but is there any reason why that wouldn't be the case?

Comment: Board layout and schematic please.

Comment: What current is your wall supply rated for? Your regulator can't put out more power than it takes in. Does the input voltage to the regulator drop when the Rasp. Pi is connected?

Comment: This can as well be a problem of a weak 12 V supply. Can you please provide a schematic of the buck regulator and data about the capabilities of the 12 V supply?

Comment: Oscillograms of input, output and SW node please.

Comment: I suppose you measured 4.6V. Can you also measure the regulator's input voltage  as @GodJihyo suggested. Also measure the regulator output which might be different from the Raspberry Pi input.

Comment: *The circuit and passive elements are exactly what is listed and recommended in the datasheet.* So don't you think to get an answer, you'd answer the concerns expressed in the comments.  Principally, what are the ratings of the wall-wart.